# HK2 cannot inject Boolean into boolean

Tags: java, dependency-injection, hk2

I'm providing a boolean for injection to HK2 like this:

`binder.bind(disableMyFeature).named("disableMyFeature").to(Boolean.class)`

Then I tried to inject it like this:

`@Named("disableMyFeature") final boolean disableMyFeature`

But I got this exception:

```
A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=boolean,parent=MyService,qualifiers={@javax.inject.Named(value="disableMyFeature")},position=11,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,381397683)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of my.package.MyService errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on my.package.MyService
```

If I change the class of this line to `Boolean`, the injection works:

`@Named("disableMyFeature") final Boolean disableMyFeature`

Which is weird because I can mix `Integer` and `int`, or `Double` and `double` and HK2 can inject them with no issue.

HK2 can even inject this:

`binder.bind(disableMyFeature).named("disableMyFeature").to(boolean.class)`

into this:

`@Named("disableMyFeature") final Boolean disableMyFeature`

So, why does HK2 have problems with injecting from `Boolean -> boolean` if it can inject from `boolean -> Boolean` and other boxed classes to primitives?

Comment: I'm very surprised you can inject anything into a final field.  Can you show more of the code?

Comment: In that code what is final is the argument of my constructor. Which part of the code do you want to see?